# Why would the electric field force be constant?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, acceleration

here in this example in the Serway book it says:
[image]

But the field should weaken the further you go from the source right? I mean if the force was constant  and doesn't decrease with distance shouldn't we be able to build some sort of train with 2 electric plates at the ends of the tunnel?

Comment: If you think of electric field lines then if the electric field lines got weaker (smaller density of electric field lines)  where would they go?

Comment: It is a basic problem in an introductory text. It explicitly states that it is a uniform electric field. While it is good to always keep an eye out in physics, here they are trying to simplify the situation to get to fundamental principles.

Comment: @Farcher I know but my intuition tells me otherwise! Think about the train idea I mentioned above

Comment: @JonCuster I see

Comment: So your positive train moves across to the negative plate and then what? The negative plate has less charge and how do you get back to the positive plate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idealization of a uniform electric field can be created with the idealization of "infinitely large plates".  Since you don't work with infinitely large plates normally, your intuition may lead you astray.

In your train example, yes you can set this up, but the field deviates significantly from uniform as the distance between the plates approaches the size of the plates.  A rather large large plate of 10m in length is only going to give a mostly uniform field for a few meters in front.  Past that the field is distorted by edge effects.

As long as the distance from the plate is much less than the distance to any edge of the plate, the field will be approximately uniform.